# Magento2 composer install fails due to magento/module-worldpay

Tags: magento2

Getting the following error when trying to composer install community edition v2.1.0:

> - Installing magento/module-worldpay (100.0.5)
>     Downloading: Connecting...
>
> [Composer\Downloader\TransportException]
>   Invalid credentials for 'https://repo.magento.com/archives/magento/module/worldpay/magento-module-worldpay-100.0.5.0.zip', aborting.

Answer (score 1):

The Magento 2 GitHub repository requires you to authenticate. The composer install commands fails if you do not. To authenticate, [generate authentication keys](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/install-gde/prereq/connect-auth.html), after which you create an auth.json file in the home directory of the Magento file system owner
For example, if your user name is magento_user, create or edit /home/magento_user/.composer/auth.json

```
{
   "github-oauth": {
     "github.com": "<your github oauth id>"
   },
   "http-basic": {
      "repo.magento.com": {
         "username": "<public key>",
         "password": "<private key>"
      }
   }
}
```

Find the detailed instructions [here](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/install-gde/prereq/dev_install.html#instgde-prereq-compose-clone-auth)

Answer (score 0):

You need to create API keys in order to download the magento2 modules.

- Go to magentocommerce.com
- In My Account > Developers > Secure Keys, generate new ones.
- Let composer create/update the auth.json file for you
- Execute:

  composer global config http-basic.repo.magento.com YOUR_PUBLIC_KEY YOUR_PRIVATE_KEY